# Access DApps publicly

Tags: blockchain, ether, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have created my own private blockchain network in LAN.I am using `admin.peer()` function for adding a new peer to network,for this  `admin.peer` function to work I need an IP address.So my question is that When I create a DApps in my own private blockchain network.How others can access DApps publicly?

Comment: Yes, I also faced this issue its possible that you can access Dapps publically.

Comment: the only way for others to know about your blockchain is markting it

Answer (score 2):

If your Dapp has a frontend, you could deploy it on a server and host it to some web address (e.g mydapp.com) and give people that url. If you want people to connect directly to your blockchain with a client (geth, parity, etc) they should the same as you used to create your private network.

For example if you  used geth:

- Share the genesis file
- Init blockchain
- add peer
  keep in mind that nodes have to be on the same network or have public IP's in order to connect.

Comment: Is there any other possible options rather than add peer using public IP address

Comment: having all peers on the same network should avoid the need for a public IP. Having a bootnode is another option, in that case only the bootnode has to have a public IP, still to connect over the internet. 
Using a tunneling app might solve your issue, but i haven't used them. (something similar to hamachi logmein)